# How to add variable amount of field sets into database and retrive them [Classic ASP]

Tags: javascript, jquery, database-design, asp-classic, relational-database

I have a form where you can add a location, which contains a set of ten text fields and drop downs. How would I go about getting the total amounts of location sets that have been added submitted to the database properly? Here is my current code that submits everything to the Database.

```
<%
If (CStr(Request("MM_insert")) = "Form") Then
  If (Not MM_abortEdit) Then
    ' execute the insert
    Dim MM_editCmd

    Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_Logistics_STRING
    MM_editCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Project (Title, PT_Num, Status, P_Month, Reg_ID, Course_Code, Duration, Des_ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Launch_Date, Pro_Des, Business_Unit, Legacy_Group, Work_Group, Notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
    MM_editCmd.Prepared = true
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Title")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param2", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-ptNum")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param3", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Dropdown-status")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param4", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Dropdown-month")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param5", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-requestor")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param6", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-curriculum")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param7", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-duration")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param8", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-designer")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param9", 135, 1, 255, MM_IIF(Request.Form("Form-Date-startDate"), Request.Form("Form-Date-startDate"), null)) ' adDBTimeStamp
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param10", 135, 1, 255, MM_IIF(Request.Form("Form-Date-endDate"), Request.Form("Form-Date-endDate"), null)) ' adDBTimeStamp
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param11", 135, 1, 255, MM_IIF(Request.Form("Form-Date-launchDate"), Request.Form("Form-Date-launchDate"), null)) ' adDBTimeStamp
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param12", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Paragraph-projectDescription")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param13", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Dropdown-businessUnit")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param14", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Dropdown-legacyGroup")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param15", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Dropdown-workGroup")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param16", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Form-Paragraph-notes")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Execute
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close

    ' append the query string to the redirect URL
    Dim MM_editRedirectUrl
    MM_editRedirectUrl = "index.asp"
    If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
      If (InStr(1, MM_editRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "?" & Request.QueryString
      Else
        MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "&" & Request.QueryString
      End If
    End If
    Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl)
  End If
End If
%>
```

And here is the current layout of my Database
[image]

With main focus paid to the Location Table as this will store the variable data set information.

Retriving this information back would be another can of worms as the user would want to edit these items. I would need to know how many sets there are, and use JQuery to build these sets out and somehow use asp to feed the data back in for all of the fields in correct order... Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is `location set` ?

Comment: I have a button on my form that says "Add Location" once the user clicks this there is a set of ten textfields and dropdowns that the user can enter information into, with the ability of adding additional locaitons. I called them "sets" since they are essentially groups of ten fields that you can continually add to a variable armount.